# piwik don't show install page

Tags: php, matomo

I install piwik on debian but when go to piwik.my_domain_name the configuring page don't show and the below information shows .

```
><?php
>/**
 >* Piwik - free/libre analytics platform
> *
 >* @link http://piwik.org
> * @license http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html GPL v3 or later
 >*
> * @package Piwik
> */`enter code here`

>if (!defined('PIWIK_DOCUMENT_ROOT')) {
>    define('PIWIK_DOCUMENT_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) == '/' ? '' : >
dirname(__FILE__));
}
if (file_exists(PIWIK_DOCUMENT_ROOT . '/bootstrap.php')) {
    require_once PIWIK_DOCUMENT_ROOT . '/bootstrap.php';
}
if (!defined('PIWIK_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
    define('PIWIK_INCLUDE_PATH', PIWIK_DOCUMENT_ROOT);
}

>require_once PIWIK_INCLUDE_PATH . '/core/bootstrap.php';

>if (!defined('PIWIK_PRINT_ERROR_BACKTRACE')) {
    define('PIWIK_PRINT_ERROR_BACKTRACE', false);
}

>require_once PIWIK_INCLUDE_PATH . '/core/dispatch.php';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have somehow inserted a bunch of extra `>` signs, as well as the text `` `enter code here` ``, to the Piwik `index.php` file. Additionally, you appear to not have PHP configured on your web server.

Install PHP on your web server, then unpack a fresh copy of Piwik.

Answer (score 1):

apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt

this command resolve my problem.

Comment: For PHP7 (e.g., Ubuntu 16.04), it is _sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php php-mcrypt_